# How to enable MySQL with PHP 7

Tags: php, mysql, php-7

I know that this is deprecated and MSQLI and PDO are the alternatives. But I have developed a CMS in which I am still using MySQL. and it will take weeks to change all the quires.
**So is there any solution that I can use MYSQL with PHP 7 now? or it's impossible.**

```
mysql_connect()
mysql_select_db()
```

etc

Comment: Those functions are deprecated  from PHP 5.5.0 and removed from php 7. You have to use the alternatives.

Comment: Even if there's a way to workaround, you should get to work and change this ASAP to `PDO`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) you have alot of reasons to motivate you.

Comment: write your own mysql_* with mysqli/pdo inside

Answer (score 2):

If you like PDO and still want to use mysql_*-functions, try this: https://github.com/JaroslavHerber/php-mysql2pdo

It creates old mysql_*-functions for PHP7+ and uses a PDO-object in background.
It was helpful for me to run plenty of old scripts on PHP7.

Answer (score 0):

if you still use those functions you should stop it right now, because, PHP 7 no longer support those functions, it only works until PHP 5.6. Otherwise, we should now use MySQLi or PDO.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/e-sites/php-mysql-mysqli-wrapper wraps `mysqli_*` functions within their old `mysql_*` counterparts and it works like a charm. It requires the `mysqli` extension.

If you don't want to edit legacy applications to `include()`/`require()` it, you can use the `auto_prepend_file` ini directive to transparently `require()` it instead.